# co-authorship network from bibtex

Tags: bibtex, tools, author

I am looking for a tool to generate a co-authorship network from a bibtex file. I guess it should be something that lot of people have already done but I cannot find anything. Before writing something from scratch I prefer to ask here as I it's the place where I think I have the highest probability to find someone who already did such a thing!

Comment: I think you mean something to know who modified the bibtext?  It's not what I am thinking about. I was thinking about something that will read the bibtex file to generate a network like this : https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2721762/bin/pntd.0000501.g002.jpg (a network of co-authorship from this paper : https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2721762/)

Comment: The [bibliometrix](http://www.bibliometrix.org/) package in R can do this, and more, or you can use [VOSViewer](http://www.vosviewer.com/). Neither has a connection to `LaTeX` unless you want to make dynamic documents with `knitr` or `markdown`.

Comment: oh thank you! I also found one python package that does the job (https://github.com/sciunto-org/python-bibtexparser) and I started to write a small script to generate a edgelist from it (draft here: https://framagit.org/sc/pybibnet). It works pretty well but I will look at the R package too